# string Concatenation is not working perl ( perl 5.10)

Tags: perl, string-concatenation

```
my $url =
'http://www.ceo.kerala.gov.in/electoralroll/edetailListAjax.html?distNo=&
lacNo=&electorName=&houseName=&epicNo='.$card_number.'&relationName=&sEcho=1&iColumns=8&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&iSortingCols=1&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&bSortable_0=false&bSortable_1=false&bSortable_2=false&bSortable_3=false&bSortable_4=false&bSortable_5=false&bSortable_6=false&bSortable_7=false&undefined=undefined';
```

while printing I am just getting

```
&relationName=&sEcho=1&iColumns=8&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&iSortingCols=1&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&bSortable_0=false&bSortable_1=false&bSortable_2=false&bSortable_3=false&bSortable_4=false&bSortable_5=false&bSortable_6=false&bSortable_7=false&undefined=undefined
```

even I use join but answer is same, please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: If I moved $card_number in the end then it is working....

Comment: I changed the syntax highlighting of your post, but I guess it is not reflecting the way your actual code looks. Please [edit] your post and paste the exact code. I copied your code and it is working for me.

Comment: your code works for me... what is $card_number? an example?

Comment: You could also go `my $url = "http://example.org/foo?bar=$baz&asdf=123";`. The double quotes will make perl insert the variable's value. But it will just be as unreadable as this is. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible if your `$card_number = "\r"` before the concatenation since  `"\r"` places the cursor at the beginning of the line, on the terminal. Test the code after putting a `$card_number = ""` before you set the `url`.